# What is it like to run programs at ISA level?

Tags: process, operating-system, instruction-set

In a computer system, the ISA level is lower than the OS level. The OS level is built upon the ISA level.

At the OS level, different programs run in different processes.

- A program can run before another program finishes running, by context switching.
- Programs in different processes do not affect each other.

Assume there is no OS and there is only one cpu core in the computer system. At the ISA level, there does not exist the concept of process. what is it like to run different programs?

- must a program start to run after the previous program finishes running?
- can the previous finished program affect the following program, in an untended or intended way?

Comment: 'there does not exist the concept of process. what is it like to run different programs?' - what?  You mean drivers?

Comment: I think drivers exist at the OS level. So at the ISA level, there is no concept of device driver?

Answer (score 1):

The question "what is it like" sounds like a question about how the processor feels about running the instructions it is given. It just runs them.

It is not true entirely that there wouldn't be a concept of a process on ISA level. Processors may have hardware support for task switching, so they might actually know about them. Of course the OS will still be running the show.

Simply put, at the ISA level the software meets the hardware. So the single core CPU will just churn instructions and command peripherals from a preset memory location onwards until it's turned off or halts otherwise. Is there some other specific question about "what is it like"?

Comment: Thanks. (1) " the single core CPU will just churn instructions and command peripherals from a preset memory location onwards until it's turned off or halts otherwise". How can I tell the cpu to run a program that is unrelated from the previous one?  (2) can the previous finished program affect the following program, in an untended or intended way?

Comment: @Tim It depends on the CPU. On some just jump to a new location in memory. On some set up memory mappings etc and jump. What the OS does when it wants to do that. Timers and interrupts. If the code running does a crappy job, anything can happen. The processor doesn't care or know.

Comment: do you mean the previous program can influence the following program in an unintended way? How can I prevent that?